# Can I use the WSO2 Api Manager with my own API Gateway?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I was thinking of using my own custom api gateway running on a separate box using nginx.

Is there any way in which the WSO2 API Manager can integrate to my api gateway?

In case there isn't, wanted to know if there's the possibility to run WSO2 API Manager without (or disabling) the API Gateway and if you could tell me which WSO2 API Manager's features would be unavailable.

Comment: What type of Gateway you have? Is it another instance of wso2 APIManager? or some other third party server?

Comment: No, it would be a non wso2 3rd party api gateway.

Comment: Then i do not think it would be easy. You have to install the gateway features in that 3rd party server. WSO2 features can be installed in wso2 servers only.

Comment: Suppose that i got those features in that other gateway, could api manager work without api gateway? At least just as a documentation repository?

Comment: What do you mean by API Gateway? In WSO2 API Manager, we have API Store, API Publisher, API Gateway and Key Manager as components. API Gateway is the main component in WSO2 API Manager. And all these components are integrated out of the box. And there are no specification, how to integrate API Gateway to a API Manager. Every vendors have their own version of API Gateway.

Comment: What I mean is, I 've decided to use an in-house solution to expose my apis, authenticate and authorize access to my apis. Now I 'm looking for a tool to host and publish APIs documentation so that users of the api can browse it and test it right from the documentation web page.

I was reading about WSO2 Api Manager and realized it has that functionality but it seems that it also includes the functionality of api gateway which I won't need as it will be implemented in an in-house component. What I was asking is if I could merge my component with WSO2 AM or if I can use WS02 AM without it's GW.

Comment: I think, you have misunderstood the API Gateway and a backend service. You can expose your documentation as APIs through WSO2 API Manager. Your backend will serve the APIs to user while user's interaction can be controlled through API Manager. Is that your are expecting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there's no way of replacing the gateway since we do the authentication, throttling, etc using synapse handlers. Here I am not sure about your use case of using nginx but what you can do is you can use nginx endpoint when you create the API or on the other way around you can route nginx traffic to API Gateway (you need to fix the API endpoints appearing in the API manager store view to point to nginx). Basically API layer need to be on top of service layer.

Answer (score 0):

> I 'm looking for a tool to host and publish APIs documentation so
>   that users of the api can browse it and test it right from the
>   documentation web page

If i got it correctly, you need a API store only to host your APIs.You can try [enterprise store](http://wso2.com/products/enterprise-store/) The documentation can be found [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ES100/WSO2+Enterprise+Store)